# Forward http port 8000 to https

Tags: web

I can forward port 8000 to 443 using `localtunnel`

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Then use it with `lt -p 8000`

I got my local port exposed to internet with subdomain https://random-xxx-xx.loca.lt

What software can forward http port to https in local only ?

From http://localhost:8000 to https://localhost

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NGINX](https://nginx.org/) [proxy_pass directive](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

using this config for example:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:443;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good recomends, but are you know more simple than `NGINX proxy pass` , i found `ssl-proxy` , `npm install -g ssl-proxy` and use it with `ssl-proxy --source 443 --target 8000` , the problem is when visiting 'localhost.dev', browser cant load, because ssl error, I've edit my /etc/hosts with `127.0.0.1 localhost.dev`

Comment: @LexaVey .dev is Top Level Domain, it doesn't work without record in /etc/hosts or DNS server, only localhost is by default resolved to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I've mention `I've edit my /etc/hosts with 127.0.0.1 localhost.dev`

Comment: anyway, my real problem is my url only on http and has running in port 8000, i want develop local with `https://local.com`, offcourse need edit `/etc/passwd` file, now i am only can use https://localhost with `ssl-proxy` i cant use `https://local.com`, i dont know why